# Is there a way to sum over an index level in a dataframe while preserving index levels that are repeated?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7, multi-index

I have a Dataframe that looks something like:

```
                     2000 2001 2002 2003
Area Item Unit Code  
A    X    j    00    val  val  val  val
A    Y    k    01    val  val  val  val
A    Z    k    10    val  val  val  val
B    X    j    00    val  val  val  val
B    Y    k    01    val  val  val  val
B    Z    k    10    val  val  val  val
```

I want to sum the areas to produce a DataFrame that looks like:

```
                     2000 2001 2002 2003
Area Item Unit Code  
C    X    j    00    val  val  val  val
C    Y    k    01    val  val  val  val
C    Z    k    10    val  val  val  val
```

If I use `df = df.sum(level = "Item")`, the rest of the index gets dropped and I get (which I expected):

```
     2000 2001 2002 2003
X    val  val  val  val
Y    val  val  val  val
Z    val  val  val  val
```

I can do `df = pd.concat([df], keys = ["C"], names = ["Area"])`, to get solve the "Area" aspect but that doesn't help with the rest of the index.

I can't find a way to sum the area data whilst preserving the structure of the DataFrame.

My actual dataframe is larger than the example I've given (`Area` values go `A B C ... ZY ZZ` etc).

Comment: Please share a reproducible problem. Give a sample of *actual values*, not `val`

Comment: This is a very good question. Deserving of equally good answer. I'm sorry I cannot help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `sum` by all levels without first `Area`, then create new column filled by `C`, add to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True` and last [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) for first position of this column:

```
print (df)
                     2000  2001  2002  2003
Area Item Unit Code                        
A    X    j    0       10    10    10    10
     Y    k    1       10    10    10    10
     Z    k    10      10    10    10    10
B    X    j    0       10    10    10    10
     Y    k    1       10    10    10    10
     Z    k    10      10    10    10    10


df1 = (df.sum(level = ["Item","Unit","Code"])
         .assign(Area = 'C')
         .set_index('Area', append=True)
         .reorder_levels([3,0,1,2]))
print (df1)
                     2000  2001  2002  2003
Area Item Unit Code                        
C    X    j    0       20    20    20    20
     Y    k    1       20    20    20    20
     Z    k    10      20    20    20    20
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = (df.sum(level = ["Item","Unit","Code"])
         .assign(Area = 'C')
         .reset_index()
         .set_index(["Area", "Item","Unit","Code"]))
print (df1)
                     2000  2001  2002  2003
Area Item Unit Code                        
C    X    j    0       20    20    20    20
     Y    k    1       20    20    20    20
     Z    k    10      20    20    20    20
```